# Many-to-Many Assignment Problem Algorithm with Constraints

Tags: algorithm, many-to-many, many-to-one, hungarian-algorithm, stable-marriage

I am trying to find the best algorithm for an assignment problem I am working on. Here is the situation:

- There are n number of agents that are each assigned some number s of tasks, where s is the number of sessions (1-4), so each agent has exactly one task for each session
- There are m number of total tasks that can be in any of the s number of sessions (1-4)
- Each task has some max number of agents that can assigned to it
- Each agent-task pair has some value that is the "happiness" of that pair

I need the algorithm to assign the agents and tasks in such a way that every agent has a task in each session and the total "happiness" is maximized for all the agents. I tried to use the Hungarian Algorithm to solve this problem; however, as it only is designed to work in a one-to-one situation, I ran into issues with that algorithm.

Comment: What have you tried yet? Where are you facing an issue?

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm that guarantees an optimal solution? Or is a greedy algorithm good enough?

Comment: If an agent can have the same task in multiple sessions, then you can solve this as a max flow problem.  Otherwise not.

Comment: (otherwise you can still use a mixed integer program solver)